# Is there an "Inspect Element" option on any browser on Android?

Tags: browser, firefox-for-android, developer-options, html

I often find myself missing the option of "Inspect element" in Android version of the popular web browsers. Do you happen to know any alternatives or workarounds that you could implement to have access this option?

There is of course the line below but that returns all of the page source and not the interesting parts.

```
view-source:webpage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dago Browser (Web Inspector)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oscarperdanakusuma.dagobrowser). It allows you to inspect webpages and works flawlessly on my MIUI8.

From its description,

> Dago Browser is a web browser with web inspector that can be opened by swipe right from a web browser page and choosing Inspect Element. Once open, it highlights the node on the page as it is selected in the hierarchy. [...]

Answer (score 2):

You can connect your phone to a PC or Mac and inspect the device from there. For example if you have Chrome open on your device and you connect it to a PC, open Chrome on the PC and from the development tools you can click on the three dots menu (on the top right, next to the X that closes the dev tools)  and then click 'more tools' --> 'Remote devices'. From there you can inspect what you see on your device.

Similar methods exist for other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

[Kiwi browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) has added the Chrome dev tools to its Android app.

It allows you to view and inspect webpages from a different tab. Unlike viewing the HTML source, you can view page updates in real-time.

It also has a JS console and other features.

You can use Android split screen and move a tab to another window to see both the inspector and page at the same time

> [image: inspecting a website]

> [image: console for webpage]

> [image: example both at the same time]

Answer (score 0):

There is this one recently released, focuses on features for developers. You can visually inspect elements: [Dev Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cleverextract.devbrowser).

From its description,

> **Inspect web elements**
>
> - Inspect and edit individual web elements and their attributes with the built-in web inspector

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inspect HTML, CSS or maybe you need JS console in your mobile browser . You can use eruda tool which provide ability to use the same Developer Tools on your mobile browser as in your desctop device. Dont forget to upvote :) Here is a link https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

Answer (score 0):

Bookmark these lines of codes:

```
javascript:(function () { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"; document.body.appendChild(script); script.onload = function () { eruda.init() } })();
```

and do the following steps shown in the screenshots. That's it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript on Opera Mini.

1. Reset the console output by opening a new tab with the address: `debug:resetconsole`
   [image: Reset output]
2. Open a tab on the page on which you want to do the inspection:
   [image: example.com]
3. Run JavaScript code on the page by replacing the address in the address bar with the following address: `javascript:var%20n%3Ddocument.firstChild%3Bwhile%28n%20%26%26%20n.nodeType%21%3DNode.ELEMENT_NODE%29%20n%3Dn.nextSibling%3Bconsole.log%28n.outerHTML%29%3B`
4. Retrieve the output by opening a new tab with the address `debug:console`
   [image: Output]